# How to visualize a permutation graph?

Tags: graphics, graphs-and-networks

Starting with:

```
Needs["Combinatorica`"]
p = {4, 5, 1, 3, 2, 6};
g = PermutationGraph[p]
```

I would like to know how to visualize the graph object that is returned by PermutationGraph

Comment: try `ShowGraph[g]`?

Comment: I did ( of course ), Mathematica (Combinatorica?) became quite unstable. But a resource function did ( a beginning of ) the work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think using [`PermutationGraph`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/PermutationGraph/) from the Wolfram Function Repository is the cleanest solution.

```
p = {4, 5, 1, 3, 2, 6};
ResourceFunction["PermutationGraph"][p]
```

[image]

Comment: I will try that now.

Comment: And this works... Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

```
pGraph1 = Graph[#, UndirectedEdge@@@Select[Not@*OrderedQ]@Subsets[#, {2}], ##2]&;

p = {4, 5, 1, 3, 2, 6};

pGraph1[p, GraphStyle -> "NameLabeled"]
```

[image]

```
SeedRandom[123];
p2 = RandomWord["Noun", 9]
```

> {"organs", "acetylene", "distaste", "hybrid", "hymen", "racism", >     "prodigal", "decampment", "surcease"}

```
pGraph1[p2, 
 VertexShapeFunction -> (Text[Framed[Style[#2, 16, Black], 
    Background -> White, FrameStyle -> None], #] &)]
```

[image]

We can also use [`RelationGraph`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RelationGraph.html):

```
pGraph2 = RelationGraph[{x, y} |-> 
   Order[x, y] != Order @@ Flatten[PositionIndex[#] /@ {x, y}], #, ##2] &;

pGraph2[p, GraphStyle -> "NameLabeled"]
```

[image]